# What options for web site development for iPad are available?

Tags: ipad, remote-debugging

I'm developing a site one of the targets of which is iPad.
What options do I have to debug client side (DOM inspector, style viewer/editor, javascript console, network analyzer - all thing every major desktop browser has) when viewing the site from iPad?

I'm not looking for some kind firebug lite, or anything that makes me to debug site from iPad itself. (This would be too tedious.) Instead, what I'm after is some sort of remote debugger for mobile Safary, allowing me to work with sites opened on iPad from a desktop machine, or an iPad emulator with same capabilities. I know there is the emulator that comes in bundle with official SDK, but does it have such means?

It's the first time I'm facing the problem, so not to blame!

This is what I'm aware of:

- [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) (But does it really work?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) and their [HTML5 (javascript) installation](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/html5)